# jQuery AutoComplete - Can't Get Data to Load

Tags: jquery, json, greasemonkey, jquery-autocomplete

I'm hoping someone can help me out. I'm building a GreaseMonkey script to modify an existing page to add additional functionality. As part of this I'm trying to add AutoComplete to a text-box using JQuery. I'm new to jQuery, so I'm probably doing something silly wrong, but I've been staring at this for too long.

This is what a normal request Body Looks Like:

```
 ["Mc"]
```

This is what the HTTP Response Looks Like:

```
"[{\"__type\":\"\",\"key\":\"62bb420a-5f3a-4a99-97b1-115beaa29b8e\",\"value\":\"McDonalds\",\"html\":null,\"data\":new Data.Dictionary(\"\",[[\"ARGSTCode\",null],[\"APGSTCode\",null],[\"ContactDefaultCurrency\",\"CURR/USD\"],[\"OrganisationTemplate\",\"\"],[\"Discount\",\"\"],[\"ContactDefaultBillDueDate\",\"\"],[\"ContactDefaultBillDueType\",null],[\"ContactDefaultBillDueTypeDisplay\",\"of the following month\"],[\"ContactDefaultInvoiceDueDate\",\"\"],[\"ContactDefaultInvoiceDueType\",null],[\"ContactDefaultInvoiceDueTypeDisplay\",\"of the following month\"],[\"DefaultAPContactAccountType\",\"\"],[\"DefaultARContactAccountType\",\"\"],[\"DefaultARTrackingCategories\",\",,,\"],[\"DefaultAPTrackingCategories\",\",,,\"]])},{\"__type\":\"\",\"key\":\"df8fd73c-1016-4bf7-a448-257c0414af9f\",\"value\":\"Mortgage\",\"html\":null,\"data\":new Data.Dictionary(\"\",[[\"ARGSTCode\",null],[\"APGSTCode\",null],[\"ContactDefaultCurrency\",\"CURR/USD\"],[\"OrganisationTemplate\",\"\"],[\"Discount\",\"\"],[\"ContactDefaultBillDueDate\",\"\"],[\"ContactDefaultBillDueType\",null],[\"ContactDefaultBillDueTypeDisplay\",\"of the following month\"],[\"ContactDefaultInvoiceDueDate\",\"\"],[\"ContactDefaultInvoiceDueType\",null],[\"ContactDefaultInvoiceDueTypeDisplay\",\"of the following month\"],[\"DefaultAPContactAccountType\",\"\"],[\"DefaultARContactAccountType\",\"\"],[\"DefaultARTrackingCategories\",\",,,\"],[\"DefaultAPTrackingCategories\",\",,,\"]])}]";/*
```

This is what my code looks like which is adding the Auto-Complete

```
$('.text.ajax') .each(function (index, el) {
  el.id = el.id + index;
  var a = $(el);
  a.autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
      $.ajax({
        url: Ajax.url + location.search,
        type: 'POST',
        data: '["' + request.term + '"]',
        dataType: 'json',
        ContentType: 'text/plain; charset=utf-8',
        headers: {
          'X-AjaxPro-Method': 'GetStuff'
        },
        success: function (data) {
          response($.map(data, function (item) {
            var text = v.value;
            return {
              label: item.value,
              value: item.key
            };
        }))
      },
        select: function(event, ui) {
          $(el).val = ui.item.value;
      }
    })
  }
})
});
```

Taking a look at a proxy while I type in the field, that request sends properly to the proper location, and gets the proper response, but nothing displays to show the auto-complete values.

What am I doing wrong?

Field Examples:

```
<input class='text ajax' id="test_value1" type="text" name="test_value1" maxlength="255">
<input class='text ajax' id="test_value2" type="text" name="test_value2" maxlength="255">
```

Comment: Can you isolate your code in a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) environment? This will make it easier for us to see the problem first-hand, and also play with it ourselves. I understand how this may not be possible if your application is AJAX-driven.

Comment: I've never used JSFiddle before. I'll take a look at it and see what can be done. If it can simulate the remote Ajax request, I should be able to mock something up.

Comment: I might have found part of the problem. It looks like my response might not actually be valid JSON. Since I don't control the response... I might have an interesting time fixing this.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer to my question. It turns out that my routine was not returning valid JSON data. Since I specified a dataType of "json", this meant that "success" was never being hit, since there was a parseError.

I first tried switching this over to 'script', which should have worked, but for some silly reason they have a comment char that isn't closed (/*) at the end of the string, so this didn't work either.

As a result, I changed the type to "Text", wrote my own regex routines to extract the data I needed, and everything else was good to go ;-).